# How to make a own Button Class

Tags: cocoa, xcode, button, interface-builder

I need help for make a own button class and linking this with the buttons made with Interface Builder, because a need change it background color, etc, with xcode, and this is only possible making a own button class, I think. Someone can help me, please? Thanks for advance.

Comment: For everyone's reference, this is Mac OS X programming, not iPhone programming.

Comment: Is very different for Iphone? Because, I'll make this application, after, for iphone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass NSButton if you want most of its behavior. Otherwise you can subclass NSControl to make your own button class. Either way I think you need to provide more detail about where you are stuck and what you need to know before I could provide a more specific answer.

Comment: How can I implement this in the window?

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no idea what you mean by "implement this in the window".

Comment: Sorry. I made 25 buttons (NSButton) with then Interface Builder, then, if I make this option, how can I refer this new class to put there in  the window form?

Comment: You can set the class of your objects in IB in the properties inspector so if you have a custom button like class (NSButton, NSActionCell, or whatever matches you needs) just make sure you're creating instances of that class in IB.